# How to split string and separate the data with numbers and text and other condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following piece of sql code

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CALCITRIOL 0.25mcg CAPSULE (EA' 

select 
case patindex('%[0-9]%', @str)
    when 0 then @str
    else left(@str, patindex('%[0-9]%', @str) -1 ) 

 

end, stuff(stuff(@str+'x', patindex('%[0-9][^0-9.]%', @str+'x') + 1, len(@str), ''
                  ), 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', @str) - 1, '')
```

The current output is displaying as follows

```
 CALCITROL     0.25
```

I would like to get the other data so that it should display data as follows

```
 CALCITROL     0.25  mcg  capsule (EA
```

Another example of string can be GENTAMICIN OPT SOL 5ML EACH, the current query gives me

```
GENTAMICIN OPT SOL 5
```

Expected is

```
GENTAMICIN OPT SOL 5 ML EACH
```

Here is the sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/132229/0

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data as well as the results.  (3) A Fiddle can help.  Someone with your rep should know these things.

Comment: I had it as part of my question

Comment: I think you might need a more sophisticated method of putting a space before the units, for example there might be a product named "Olsafinil Maladene 25". It is usual to format the data for display in the front-end part of the application, rather than in the database - it could be simpler that way.

Comment: I am trying this logic over back end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a third column:

```
case patindex('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@str))
    when 0 then ''
    else REVERSE(left(REVERSE(@str), patindex('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@str)) -1 )) END
```

This gets most of the way there:

```
declare @fullstr table (bigstr varchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS);
INSERT INTO @fullstr
VALUES
('ARANESP 100mcg PFS SOLD BY THE'),('ARANESP 25mcg PFS SOLD BY THE'),('ARANESP 40mcg PFS SOLD BY THE'),
('ARANESP 60mcg PFS SOLD BY THE'),('CALCITRIOL 0.25mcg CAPSULE (EA'),('CALCITRIOL ORAL .50mcg EACH'),
('CEFAZOLIN SODIUM 1gm EACH MMS'),('CEFTAZIDIME INJ 1gm SDV "EACHE'),('CINACALCET HCL 30mg 30/BT SLAT'),
('CINACALCET HCL 60mg 30/BT 100'),('CINACALCET HCL 90mg 30/BT'),('EPOGEN 10 000/ML MDV 2ml "EA"'),
('EPOGEN 20 000 U/ML MDV 1ml "EA"'),('EPOGEN 2000U/ML 1ml "EA" SOLD'),('EPOGEN 3000U/ML 1ml "EA" SOLD'),
('EPOGEN 4000U/ML 1ml "EA" SOLD'),('GENTAMICIN OPT SOL 5ml EACH'),('GENTAMICIN SULFATE 0.1% CREAM'),
('GENTAMICIN SULFATE 80MG/2ml CT'),('Heparin Sod Inj USP 30 000 uni'),('LEVOFLOXACIN 250mg TAB EACH 50'),
('LEVOFLOXACIN TAB 500mg "SOLD A'),('LIDOCAINE/PRILOCAINE 2.5% 30GM'),('VANCOMYCIN FTV 1gm "EA" 10/BX'),
('VANCOMYCIN FTV 500mg "EA" 10/B'),('VENOFER 20MG/ML 5ml (100mg) EA'),('WATER STERILE FTV 10ml "EA" 25');

declare @replaces table (id int identity (100,1), units varchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS);

INSERT INTO @replaces (units) VALUES ('Fluid Extract'),('Concentrate'),('Injectable'),('Suspension'),('tbu/0.1ml'),('62.5mg/ml'),
                                        ('Diaphragm'),('Emulsion'),('Crystals'),('Granules'),('Lollipop'),('ounce(s)'),('units/ml'),
                                        ('Tincture'),('Solution'),('Shampoo'),('Pudding'),('mg/10ml'),('5mcg/ml'),('2mcg/ml'),
                                        ('UNKNOWN'),('dose(s)'),('Lozenge'),('Implant'),('Inhaler'),('Aerosol'),('Device'),('lotion'),
                                        ('Leaves'),('Liquid'),('Elixir'),('Flakes'),('Insert'),('bottle'),('MCG/ml'),('scoops'),
                                        ('tbu/ml'),('MG/2ml'),('GM/5ml'),('MG/tab'),('Tampon'),('Pellet'),('Powder'),('Spirit'),
                                        ('Troche'),('UKNOWN'),('Wafer'),('Paste'),('Syrup'),('Strip'),('Sheet'),('patch'),
                                        ('spray'),('stick'),('units'),('mg/ml'),('liter'),('MG/kg'),('MG/m2'),('cream'),('L/min'),
                                        ('Beads'),('Enema'),('Film'),('Disk'),('Foam'),('tape'),('oint'),('mask'),('appl'),('gtts'),
                                        ('inch'),('MG/g'),('tbsp'),('supp'),('puff'),('Ring'),('Swab'),('Wax'),('Tar'),('tbu'),
                                        ('pkg'),('tab'),('tsp'),('bag'),('bar'),('can'),('cap'),('mcg'),('meq'),('Gas'),('Gel'),
                                        ('IUD'),('Kit'),('Gum'),('Oil'),('Pad'),('mg'),('ml'),('iu'),('gm'),('gr'),('%');

;WITH cte AS 
(SELECT REPLACE(bigstr, r.units, '##' + cast(r.id as varchar(3)) + '§§') translated
FROM @fullstr f INNER JOIN @replaces r On f.bigstr LIKE '%' + units + '%' 
WHERE  REPLACE(bigstr, r.units, '##' + cast(r.id as varchar(3)) + '§§') <> bigstr)

select 
case charindex('##'+CAST(r.id as char(3))+'§§', translated)
    when 0 then translated
    else REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(left(translated, charindex('##'+CAST(r.id as char(3))+'§§', translated) -1 )), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(left(translated, charindex('##'+CAST(r.id as char(3))+'§§', translated) -1 ))),100 ))
end, 
case charindex('##'+CAST(r.id as char(3))+'§§', translated)
    when 0 then translated
    else REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(left(translated, charindex('##'+CAST(r.id as char(3))+'§§', translated) -1 )), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(left(translated, charindex('##'+CAST(r.id as char(3))+'§§', translated) -1 ))) ))
end, 

r.Units, SUBSTRING(c.translated, charindex('§§', c.translated) + 3, 100)
FROM cte c INNER JOIN @replaces r ON SUBSTRING(c.translated, charindex('##', c.translated) + 2, 3) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  = CAST(r.id AS CHAR(3)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
ORDER BY translated
```

There remain problems: You need to observe case sensitivity in order to ensure that your dosages do not lead to joins in the wrong place.  I have the dosages lower case unless it is a combo (eg MG/2ml) in which case the first is upper case and the second bit lower.

Also your data does not match your requirement: what is supposed to happen with Heparin Sod Inj USP 30 000 uni?  I need to go out now.

Comment: Thanks it is combining mcg CAPSULE (EA, can MCG and capsule split to different columns like the first tw0

Comment: Can we connect through chat

Comment: In a meeting at the moment.  I'll get back to you

Comment: Ok let me know when you are back

Comment: I have this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e22f6/1

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into

Comment: Ist it always mcg or are there other units as well? If so do they all have the same length?

Comment: Maximum length as per the master table data I see is 13

Comment: I was talking about the units (assuming mcg are units?)

Comment: but the mostly used are MG/MCG/CAP/ML/Cream/oint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235933/discussion-between-jonathan-willcock-and-developer).

Comment: I will post a new question if heparin inj is required

Comment: Hi jonathan I created a new based on some r&D can you help me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d2781/4/0